# Alternative approaches to find $a$ from $A = A_1(1 - (1 - f)e^{-a(F - T)})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Just trying to find the correct, or proper, method to arrive at the author’s solution.
This is the article hyperlink:  [Brown 1992, page 45](https://crs-alchemy-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/pdf/crsq-1992-volume-29-number-1.pdf)

Here is the original equation

$$A = A_1(1 - (1 - f)e^{-a(F - T)})$$

This is the Brown’s solution, to define the term $a$

“To meet the requirement that $A$ has been approximately equal to $A_1$(equilibrium of C-14 in the upper biosphere) over the past 3500 years, we can use a trial setting of $A = 0.95A_1$ at $T = 4000$, from which”

$$a = \frac{ln(20(1 - f))}{F - 4000}$$ which approximates to

$$a ≈ \frac{2.996 + ln(1 - f)}{F - 4000}$$

**This is my initial methodology**

First substitute $0.95$ for the term $A$ in the original equation

$$0.95A_1 = A_1(1 - (1 - f )e^{-a(F - T)})$$

divide both sides by $A_1$, canceling out the term, resulting in

$$0.95 = 1 - (1 - f)e^{-a(F - T)}$$

add the term $((1 - f)e^{-a(F - T)})$, to both sides resulting in

$$0.95 + (1 - f)e^{-a(F - T)} = 1$$

subtract $0.95$ from both sides, resulting in

$$(1 - f)e^{-a(F - T)} = 0.05$$

since $e$ is raised to a negative exponent, the term can be expressed as  $\frac{1}{e^{a(F-T)}}$ thus the equation now becomes

$$(\frac{1}{e^{a(F - T)}})(1 - f) = 0.05$$

multiply both sides by $e^{a(F - T)}$, resulting in

$$(1 - f)(1) = 0.05e^{a(F - T)}$$

*From this point, two workflows can be used to derive the same solution*

**Workflow 1**

starting with

$$(1 - f)(1) = 0.05e^{a(F - T)}$$

divide both sides by $0.05$, resulting in

$$(1 - f)(\frac{1}{0.05}) = (1)e^{a(F - T)}$$

simplify by dividing $1$ by $0.05$ and distributing $1$ to $e^{a(F - T)}$, resulting in

$$(1 - f)(20) = e^{a(F - T)}$$
take the natural logarithm of both sides

$$ln((1 - f)(20)) = ln(e^{a(F - T)})$$

use the product rule: $ln(xy) = ln(x) + ln(y)$, therefore

$$ln(1 -f ) + ln(20) = a(F - T)$$

divide both sides by $(F-T)$

$$\frac{(ln(1 -f ) + ln(20))}{(F - T)} = a$$

substitute $4000$ for $T$ and approximate $ln(20)$, this leaves the same solution as Brown 1992

**Workflow 1 Solution** $$\frac{(ln(1 -f ) + 2.996)}{(F - 4000)} = a$$

**Workflow 2**

beginning with

$$(1 - f)(1) = 0.05e^{a(F - T)}$$

distribute $(1)$ to $(1 - f)$ resulting in

$$(1 - f) = 0.05e^{a(F - T)}$$

divide both sides by $0.05$

$$\frac{(1 - f)}{0.05} = e^{a(F - T)}$$

take the natural log of both sides

$$ln\frac{(1 - f)}{0.05}) = ln(e^{a(F - T)})$$

use the quotient rule: $ln(x/y) = ln(x) - ln(y)$, thus

$$ln(1 - f) - ln(0.05) = a(F - T)$$

divide both sides by $(F - T)$

$$\frac{(ln(1 -f ) - ln(0.05))}{(F - T)} = a$$

approximate $ln(0.05)$

$$\frac{(ln(1 -f ) - (-2.996))}{(F - T)} = a$$

simplify, note the sign change, then substitute $T = 4000$

**Workflow 2 Solution** $$\frac{(ln(1 -f ) + 2.996)}{(F - 4000)} = a$$

Both Workflow 1 and 2 equate to  $$\frac{(ln(1 -f ) + 2.996)}{(F - 4000)} = a$$

Which is the same as Brown’s solution for $a$ after he approximated $ln(20)$ and applied the product rule:

$$a ≈ \frac{2.996 + ln(1 - f)}{F - 4000}$$

I’m just not sure which of my workflows is correct, they both may be wrong, as algebra is not my strong suit.  I think that there may be a problem with distributing (1) to (1-f) in workflow 2 might be wrong, it might be just chance that the sign change from using the quotient rule is just a lucky coincidence since $ln(0.05) ≈ -2.996$ and $ln(20) ≈ 2.996$.

Anyhow, I’m sure that I did something(s) wrong here.  Any advice on my solutions and workflows that the community can give would be of great help.

Thank you in advance,

Mathmoot

PS: I'm sure that I went overboard on the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine.

Anything multiplied by $1$ is itself as $1$ is the multiplicative identity.

Also $\frac1{20}=0.05$ and hence  $-\ln 20 = \ln 0.05$.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.